# Not all Extended Ascii Characters are being converted to ASCII

Tags: java, transliteration, icu4j

Using icu4j-63.1 library we are transliterating native text to ascii character for our project. For few of the cases transliteration is not working as expected.

Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Below code is being used to transliterate

```
Transliterator any2Latin = Transliterator.getInstance("Any-Latin/UNGEGN; Latin; Title");
Transliterator latin2Ascii = Transliterator.getInstance("Latin-ASCII");
latin2Ascii.transliterate(any2Latin.transliterate(<<Input String>>))
```

Below are the list of sample text for which transliteration is not working ie., the input and output string both are same.

- THE L±NFANT TRUST (Expected to transliterate ± to +/-. But the
  output is same as the given string).
- DON¢A
- JAIME CASTA¦ON
- ENGº JOSE BARATA
- TERRY STUARDCB¬NEWTONRAY¬
- ¥YOUNG© (Here, © is successfully being converted to (C) but not Yen
  symbol. The Yen symbol remains the same post transliteration)